# Parsing 外から観た自分をとらえ、それを「こう見てほしい」という自分の実像に近づけていくことだ

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

> 自分の聞いてもらいたいことを聞いてもらえるメディアになる。
> 「メディア力を高める」とは、そういう意味だ。少し引いた目で、外から観た自分をとらえ、それを「こう見てほしい」という自分の実像に近づけていくことだ。

I wonder how I should parse this sentence

- （外から観た）自分をとらえる: I take what I see from the outside **or**
- （外から観た自分）をとらえ: To grasp what another people think about me from the outside

Should こう見てほしい という自分の実像に近づけていくことだ be translated as "I want to see this..." or "I want to be seen like this (?) （こう見てほしい） which is almost similar to the real image （自分の実像に近づけていくことだ）"

Answer (score 1):

I will divide your question into two parts.

1. 「外から観た自分をとらえ」

I think meaning of this part is ''to grasp what another people think about me.''

To see a person from outside is inevitably by another people. So I think we do not need to explicitly translate 観る as ''from the outsides.''

Japanese word 観る or 見る has really broad meaning. The root meaning is ''see''   with your eyes visually. But often we use as ''understand'' or ''think.'' In this sentence, 観る is related to a public image of the media.

2. 「それを『こう見てほしい』という自分の実像に近づけていくことだ」

それ means the public image of the media, and こと at the end is 「メディア力を高める」 in the second sentence.

So, this means ''if you want to enhance メディア力, you should make your public image close to what you really are.''

3. misc.

〜〜力（りょく） in Japanese language has wide range of use.

For example, 体力（たいりょく） means physical strength, endurance, stamina.

女子力（じょしりょく） means ability of doing housework, skill of makeup, etc.

Comment: 少し引いた目で->what this part means? それ refer to 外から観た自分をとらえ？ こう見てほしい->私の想像？ i still dont get the point><><>< could you elaborate more please?

Comment: The 引く is like 下がる, 離れる, "to step back", so 引いた目で is "look from a distance" so here 少し引いた目で is "look (at myself) from a little distance" i.e. "objectively". それ refers to 「外から観た自分」.   こう見てほしいという自分の実像 means "how you want to be seen". 「それを「こう見てほしい」という自分の実像に近づけていくこと」means "making それ (=you seen from a distance = how you are seen objectively = how you really look to others) closer to こう見てほしい自分の実像 (= how you want to be seen)"

Comment: @chocolate at first i thought it means like you see something interesting and it struck your eyes lol but real meaning is to see from yourself afar(?)->(少し引いた目で)。少し引いた目で explain 外から観た自分?

Comment: 少し引いた目で is literally like 少し離れて or 少し離れたところから (to see yourself from afar), so it means "(to look at yourself) objectively" "from an objective viewpoint". 少し引いた目で is an adverbial phrase, so it modifies the verb とらえる adverbially. Parse it: 「[(少し引いた)目で][(外から観た)自分を]とらえる」-> 「[少し離れて/客観的に][外から観た自分を]捉える」. `少し引いた目で explain 外から観た自分` -> yes I think these are saying almost the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

外から観た自分をとらえ means "to see oneself objectively". It may be close to "to take what another people see me from the outside" in your translation.

それを「こう見てほしい」という自分の実像に近づけていく means "You make it to be close to the real your image which you want people to see you like this". "it" in this sentence is 外から観た自分. I am not sure my English though.

Comment: こう見てほしい=my real image?

Comment: 自分の実像を「こう見てほしい」. It is translated as ' I want you to see my real image as(like) this.

Comment: Ok i think i got it!!! 自分の聞いてもらいたいことを聞いてもらえるメデイアになる->聞く in this sentence means understand/ask/hear? What we want people understand could be understand by people (?)

Comment: I think it means "ask". "A media which can ask what I want to ask".

Comment: One more 少し引いた目で->seen by another people? And i really want to know this one 子供を自立し大人にしなければ->where to cut part of this sentence when i want to translate it to english  ->子供を自立した//大人にしなければor 子供を自立した大人//にしなければ？？？

Comment: The subject of 少し引いた目で is "I" and it means coolly or objectively. 子供を自立した大人にする is translated as " Make children self-independent adults".

Comment: 少し引いた目で->so i cant translate it according to the word(?) is it a phrase(?) and 子供を自立した//大人にする or 子供を自立した大人//にする？

Comment: 少し引いた目で is used as adverbially, so 少し引いた目で、外から観た自分をとらえ means "I grasp myself coolly and objectively" and 外から観た自分を means "objectively" as I said. I can't understand the difference between 子供を自立した/大人にする or 子供を自立した大人/にする. Can you teach me?

Comment: Ah okay hahhaha 子供を自立した大人にしなければ->しなければ means must? Its just my own way to translate something >< sometimes i dont know where to cut the sentence when trying to understand japanese sentences><

Comment: It needs a following phrase. If ならない is omitted in 子供を自立した大人にしなければ, it means "must". However only 子供を自立した大人にしなければ make sense like "If you don't make children self-independent adults".

Comment: Ah okay got it!!!! Thankyou so much!!!!!^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Heh... I thought your conversation had been moved to the chat so I replied over there yesterday but it seems like no one has noticed  -> http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45129/discussion-between-yuuichi-tam-and-devina-muljono